# QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection'

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt

i'm trying to connect my qt application to a Mysql database and don't know why it's showing the following error message : QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
can someone help me please, this is my code :

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
  db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
  db.setUserName("root");
  db.setPassword("");
  db.setDatabaseName("pmkfinal");
  if(db.open()){
      QMessageBox::information(this,"Connection","Database Connected Successfully");
  }else{
      QMessageBox::information(this,"Connection","Database not Connected Successfully");
  }

 }
```

Thank you All !!

Answer (score 0):

Do not connect to the database repeatedly. Or you can provide an alternate connection name to avoid the warning message.